# Как получить сообщения из топика Kafka?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka

Написал типичную функцию для получения и обработки сообщений из топика Kafka. В качестве инструментов использую язык Python и модуль Confluent Kafka. При использовании метода poll() одного из consumer'ов возвращаемое значение всегда None. Реализация представлена ниже:

```python
def consume_from_kafka_topic(topic):
    conf = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',  
        'group.id': 'my_consumer_group', 
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
    }

    consumer = Consumer(conf)
    consumer.subscribe([topic])  # Подписываемся на указанный топик

    try:
        while True:
            msg = consumer.poll(1.0)  # Получаем сообщение из топика
            if msg is None:
                continue
            if msg.error():
                if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                    continue
                else:
                    print(f'Ошибка при получении сообщения: {msg.error().str()}')
                    break
            else:
                value = msg.value().decode('utf-8')  # Декодируем значение сообщения
                print(f'Получено сообщение: {value}')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    finally:
        consumer.close()
```

В логах ошибок нет, к брокеру подключение есть, так как отправка сообщений через producer'ов работает. Через kafdrop в топике отображаются 14 сообщений. Где была допущена ошибка и в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас топик так и называется банально `topic`?

Comment: Или это у вас с выравниваем в codeblock такой курьёз вышел, и весь код к функции относится?

Comment: Да, с форматированием блока кода вышел курьёз и сбилась табуляция. А название топиков выбрано схематичное, просто для примера.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, метод poll() считывает сообщения, отправленные только после момента создания consumer'a. Для считывания всех сообщений из топика пришлось вручную прописать смещение (offset) топика на 0. Добавив следующий код перед бесконечным циклом, мне удалось получить желаемый результат:

```
# Создаем объект TopicPartition с указанием топика, раздела и смещения
tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition, offset)

# Устанавливаем смещение для указанного топика и раздела
consumer.assign([tp])
```